# Scale Origin Clipped Path SVG {Camera Shutter}

Tags: svg, transform, scale

I am attempting to replicate a camera shutter and it appears as though my path is scaling from the top left, based on its position within the clipping path. I have set the transform origin to 50% but it doesnt appear to be working the way Im expecting it to. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```css
 #camera-v3c .cls-2 { fill: #231f20 }
      #camera-v3c .cls-4 { fill: #b5b6b6 }
      #camera-v3c .cls-5 { fill: #686969 }
      #camera-v3c .cls-6 { fill: #2d2e2d }
      #camera-v3c .cls-7 { fill: #434343 }
      #camera-v3c .cls-8 { fill: #575757 }
      #camera-v3c:hover #shutter{
       -webkit-transform: scale(2);
       -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
       -webkit-transition:.3s;
       transform: scale(2);
       transform-origin: 50% 50%;
       transition:.3s;
       fill: rgba(255,0,152,1);
    }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="camera-v3c" viewBox="0 0 513.88 363.34">
                <defs>
                    <radialGradient id="radial-gradient" cx="299.19" cy="215.04" r="100.4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#231f20" stop-opacity="0"/>
                        <stop offset=".44" stop-color="#231f20" stop-opacity=".43"/>
                        <stop offset=".89" stop-color="#231f20"/>
                    </radialGradient>
                    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient2" x1="207.3" x2="274.25" y1="215.04" y2="215.04" gradientTransform="matrix(0 1.3 -1 0 480 -131.87)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
                        <stop offset=".84" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
                    </linearGradient>
                    <clipPath id="clip-path">
                        <circle id="clip" cx="299.19" cy="215.04" r="100.4" fill="none"/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
                <path id="cam-light-grey4" d="m513.53 142.14-.34-.62-1.87-5.82a7.83 7.83 0 0 0 1.67-9.35l-.32-.62-4.85-9.36a8 8 0 0 0-4.53-4 13.45 13.45 0 0 0 .68-1.87 22.17 22.17 0 0 0 .59-5.33c0-8.64-4.51-12.54-6.45-13.81a7.84 7.84 0 0 0-4.31-1.29h-4.67l-.88-6a7.9 7.9 0 0 0-4.44-6v-.83a9 9 0 0 0-4.17-8.19 7.5 7.5 0 0 0-3.33-1.05c-3.74-.38-7.75-.75-11.75-1.11l1.87-14.07c1.36-10.84-11.23-14.6-15.85-16a148.6 148.6 0 0 0-23-4.58 162.16 162.16 0 0 0-19.82-1.39h-3.57c-4.47.19-15.66.64-18.71 8.91a141.13 141.13 0 0 0-6.83-13.29 7.9 7.9 0 0 0-4.79-3.63 7.9 7.9 0 0 0-1.41-5.84 93.1 93.1 0 0 0-8.85-10.38 7.9 7.9 0 0 0-4.94-2.3L307.37 0h-.65a7.88 7.88 0 0 0-3 .58 7.88 7.88 0 0 0-3-.58h-.65l-51.21 4.25a7.77 7.77 0 0 0-5 2.3A100.43 100.43 0 0 0 235 17a7.76 7.76 0 0 0-1.55 4.87 9.34 9.34 0 0 0-1.5.71 7.89 7.89 0 0 0-2.08 1.87 7.52 7.52 0 0 0-.5.75 129.26 129.26 0 0 0-7.19 13.25c-1.4-10.43-15-11.59-21.7-12.15-4.16-.34-8.93-.5-14.21-.5-4.84 0-9.95.15-15.19.43a225.53 225.53 0 0 0-29.21 3.33C135.09 30.88 121 33.65 121.61 45l.94 16.84-4.29.06a7.84 7.84 0 0 0-3.89 1.24 3.68 3.68 0 0 0 0-.47 8.63 8.63 0 0 0-1.23-3.59c-1.54-2.53-4.27-4.33-8.59-5.62a9.64 9.64 0 0 0-1-1.16c-1.14-1-3.56-3.27-14.75-3.27-1.62 0-3.35 0-5.12.15-2.53.15-5.21.39-7.94.73a91.6 91.6 0 0 0-16.98 3.59 19.62 19.62 0 0 0-7.49 4 9 9 0 0 0-1.87 2.66l-.5.28-.3.23-.6.43a15.31 15.31 0 0 0-3.26 3.22 10.63 10.63 0 0 0-1 1.7h-.39c-12.65.86-19.67 1.44-19.74 1.44h-1a7.48 7.48 0 0 0-2 .47l-3.81 1.42a7.91 7.91 0 0 0-4.15 3.74 7.83 7.83 0 0 0-5.16 5.37l-.7 2.42a7.94 7.94 0 0 0-2.95 2.41l-2.25 3A7.81 7.81 0 0 0 0 91v19.83A7.64 7.64 0 0 0 .6 114a7.64 7.64 0 0 0-.6 3l.6 211.8a7.88 7.88 0 0 0 4.28 7l.85.39a7.8 7.8 0 0 0 1.87 5.31l12.22 14.69a7.87 7.87 0 0 0 3.74 2.49 114.81 114.81 0 0 0 23.13 3.88c6.58.54 14.07.8 22.25.8 25.2 0 50.52-2.58 55.33-3.09a7.51 7.51 0 0 0 2.69-.82 8 8 0 0 0 3.22.71h314.37a8.34 8.34 0 0 0 1 0l24-3.09a7.81 7.81 0 0 0 4.75-2.45l13.83-15a7.75 7.75 0 0 0 2.22-5.46v-.39a7.86 7.86 0 0 0 2.29-5.62v-11.22a7.53 7.53 0 0 0-.53-2.69 7.68 7.68 0 0 0 .53-2.71V164a7.7 7.7 0 0 0-.83-3.46 7.87 7.87 0 0 0 .83-3.46v-2.42a33.65 33.65 0 0 0 4.73 1.16l1.46.23a9.55 9.55 0 0 0 4.94-1.09l6.25-3.65a7.88 7.88 0 0 0 3.51-9.17Z" class="cls-2"/>
                <path id="cam-light-grey3" fill="#3d3b3c" d="M198.55 213.92a100.84 100.84 0 0 0 100.84 100.84 100.84 100.84 0 1 0-100.84-100.84Z"/>
                <g id="cam-btn">
                    <path id="cam-btn-pth2" d="M106.46 63.21a8.16 8.16 0 0 0-4.23-2.21 7.3 7.3 0 0 1-2.23 2.08 20.59 20.59 0 0 1-3.09 1.52l-.88.33-1 .36c-1.72.56-3.74 1.12-6 1.63Q84 68.1 78.78 68.79c-2.66.32-5.26.56-7.73.71h-1.63a53.82 53.82 0 0 1-11.69-.58 8.88 8.88 0 0 1-3.89-1.41l-.15-.13-.32-.28h-.25l-.43.32A7.63 7.63 0 0 0 51.07 69a1.33 1.33 0 0 0-.34.74.91.91 0 0 0 .19.45 6.2 6.2 0 0 0 2.5 1.52A28.28 28.28 0 0 0 58.1 73a54.53 54.53 0 0 0 9.36 1 88.21 88.21 0 0 0 11.94-.52A85.55 85.55 0 0 0 92.29 71h.3a50.28 50.28 0 0 0 7.48-2.54 20.46 20.46 0 0 0 5.32-3.26 8.11 8.11 0 0 0 .77-.78l.2-.32a2 2 0 0 0 .23-.43.38.38 0 0 0 0-.15.71.71 0 0 0-.13-.31Z" class="cls-4"/>
    
                    <path id="cam-btn-pth1" d="M56.74 63.77a4.89 4.89 0 0 0 1.87.6h.11a51.11 51.11 0 0 0 10.63.49h1.55c2.23-.13 4.7-.36 7.39-.69q5-.62 9.9-1.71c2-.47 3.89-1 5.5-1.51 1.18-.41 2.06-.77 2.75-1.09a7.54 7.54 0 0 0 1.16-.63 2.31 2.31 0 0 0 .87-.79.49.49 0 0 0 0-.17c-.79-.71-5.77-1.55-14.15-1.07-2.23.12-4.72.34-7.49.68a81.56 81.56 0 0 0-15.38 3.24 13.09 13.09 0 0 0-4.71 2c-.19.19-.27.32-.25.38a.45.45 0 0 0 .25.27Z" class="cls-4"/>
                </g>
                <g id="cam-grey-pth1">
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth12" d="M299.21 83.29a131.74 131.74 0 1 0 0 263.47 131.74 131.74 0 0 0 0-263.47Zm0 247.57A115.82 115.82 0 1 1 415 215a116 116 0 0 1-115.81 115.86Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth11" d="M199.57 121.63a4.78 4.78 0 0 1 .54-2.06H163l-1.47 3.24h35.29a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 2.75-1.18Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth10" d="M465.61 119.54H397a4.46 4.46 0 0 1 .2.8 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 3.75 3.41h66.13l2-4.21Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth9" d="M42.81 82.48v-.67a4.17 4.17 0 0 1 0-.5v-.12l1.09-7.31c-12.13.82-19.09 1.38-19.7 1.44h-.88l-3.75 1.42C22.4 81.83 31 91.45 55.09 90.83c-7.71-1.48-11.85-4.25-12.28-8.35Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth8" d="M391.77 63.59c2.52.11 5.05.28 7.48.43-.07-.66-.3-2.12-.71-4.25l1.53-17.54a4.46 4.46 0 0 1 1.93-3.38c-6.2.48-9.06 1.87-9.36 4.53L390.6 59v.07c.68 2.41 1.07 4 1.16 4.4a.24.24 0 0 0 .01.12Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth7" d="m450.6 51.59-1.38 15.82v.09l7.26.58 2.08-16.3a3.82 3.82 0 0 0 0-.58c-.08-2.69-3.24-4.78-10.34-6.93-2.34-.69-5-1.36-7.92-2l2.38 1c5.84 2.52 8.22 5.03 7.92 8.32Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth6" d="M143.43 37.22c-5 1-8.52 2-10.79 3.19-2 1-3 2.18-3.17 3.53a4 4 0 0 0 0 .6l1 17 .15 1.87 5.71-.21h.93v-.8l-.79-18.06c-.15-3.38 3.32-5.7 11.55-7.76l.92-.22.17-.05c-1.51.23-2.94.47-4.32.72Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth5" d="m206.85 39.28.92 21.31v.59l7.72-.15h.79a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-.26h-.69a2.62 2.62 0 0 0 0-.56v-.36l-1.11-20c-.18-3.1-4.36-4.79-13.9-5.61 4.21 1 6.16 2.6 6.27 5.04Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth4" d="m128.33 69.39-9.73.41.41.58a6.09 6.09 0 0 1 1.72 3.62 6.64 6.64 0 0 1-1.73 5.17 46.87 46.87 0 0 0 12.62-7.37c.56-.47 1.08-1 1.59-1.44s.76-.81 1.12-1.22l-3.13.13Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth3" d="M299.19 110.2a103.57 103.57 0 1 0 103.57 103.57A103.57 103.57 0 0 0 299.19 110.2Zm.24 204.56a100.84 100.84 0 1 1 100.81-100.84 100.84 100.84 0 0 1-100.85 100.84Z" class="cls-5"/>
                    <path id="cam-grey-pth2" d="M299.19 101.78A113.27 113.27 0 1 0 412.46 215a113.26 113.26 0 0 0-113.27-113.22Zm0 220.45a108.52 108.52 0 1 1 108.52-108.51 108.51 108.51 0 0 1-108.52 108.51Z" class="cls-5"/>
                </g>
                <g id="cam-drk-grey">
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth7" d="m376.72 62.93-12.2-35.55-57.84-6V61c23 .36 46.48 1 70.08 2Z" class="cls-6"/>
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth6" d="m383.16 63.3 2.47.14a139.39 139.39 0 0 0-13.76-32.92l11.23 32.8Z" class="cls-6"/>
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth5" d="M101.37 338.25c-.36 0-9.72 1.12-48.21 1.12-20.58 0-32.65-1.46-39.54-2.92l12.22 14.69a108.39 108.39 0 0 0 21.54 3.57c29.94 2.42 68.88-1.51 76.1-2.28l.15-.28 9.17-17.38Z" class="cls-6"/>
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth4" d="M366.26 334.19a5.33 5.33 0 0 1-1.07.82 5 5 0 0 1-2.35.6h-.7a4.94 4.94 0 0 1-4.36 2.69 3.39 3.39 0 0 1-.78 0 4.79 4.79 0 0 1-2.21 2 5 5 0 0 1-2 .43 5.17 5.17 0 0 1-1.41-.21 4.75 4.75 0 0 1-2.5 2.25 4.93 4.93 0 0 1-1.78.33 4.21 4.21 0 0 1-1.22-.15 4.68 4.68 0 0 1-2.38 1.87 5.36 5.36 0 0 1-1.59.27 5 5 0 0 1-1.49-.23 4.86 4.86 0 0 1-2.55 1.76 4.62 4.62 0 0 1-1.38.21 4.79 4.79 0 0 1-1.59-.27 5.07 5.07 0 0 1-2.53 1.6 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-1.2.13 5.05 5.05 0 0 1-2-.43 4.78 4.78 0 0 1-2.77 1.66 5.46 5.46 0 0 1-1 0 4.83 4.83 0 0 1-2-.43 4.79 4.79 0 0 1-2.66 1.37 5.21 5.21 0 0 1-.79 0 5 5 0 0 1-2.26-.56 4.82 4.82 0 0 1-2.79 1.31h-.58a5 5 0 0 1-2.34-.6 4.86 4.86 0 0 1-2.77 1.12h-.37a4.87 4.87 0 0 1-2.88-.95 4.94 4.94 0 0 1-3.15 1.27h-.13a4.77 4.77 0 0 1-2.73-.83 4.81 4.81 0 0 1-2.79.88 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-2.92-1 4.84 4.84 0 0 1-2.71.83h-.28a4.85 4.85 0 0 1-2.77-1.07 4.91 4.91 0 0 1-2.45.65h-.47a4.93 4.93 0 0 1-3-1.45 4.9 4.9 0 0 1-2.58.74 4.09 4.09 0 0 1-.7 0 4.7 4.7 0 0 1-2.67-1.29 5.15 5.15 0 0 1-2.08.45 4.51 4.51 0 0 1-.9 0 4.93 4.93 0 0 1-2.69-1.5 4.86 4.86 0 0 1-2 .42 5.11 5.11 0 0 1-1.11-.13 4.67 4.67 0 0 1-2.54-1.52 5.26 5.26 0 0 1-1.71.3 4.38 4.38 0 0 1-1.29-.19 4.8 4.8 0 0 1-2.75-1.87 4.62 4.62 0 0 1-1.87.37 4.36 4.36 0 0 1-1.52-.24 4.77 4.77 0 0 1-2.41-1.76 4.59 4.59 0 0 1-3-.13 4.73 4.73 0 0 1-2.4-1.87 4 4 0 0 1-1.2.15 5 5 0 0 1-1.87-.37 4.83 4.83 0 0 1-2.26-1.88 6.46 6.46 0 0 1-.88 0 5 5 0 0 1-2.08-.46 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-2.3-2.27 4.71 4.71 0 0 1-.92 0 4.84 4.84 0 0 1-4.3-2.62h-92.78l-9.36 17.95v.15h314.37l23.95-3.07 14-15H366.26Z" class="cls-6"/>
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth3" d="M472 201.7v106.06c0 2.06 1.26 3.75 2.74 3.75h9.88V164c-4.76 4.56-12.62 15.38-12.62 37.7Z" class="cls-6"/>
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth2" d="M392.59 43.38c.3-2.66 3.16-4.05 9.36-4.53a4.46 4.46 0 0 0-1.88 3.38l-1.53 17.54c.41 2.13.64 3.59.71 4.25-2.43-.15-5-.32-7.48-.43a.24.24 0 0 1 0-.08.09.09 0 0 0 0 .12q25.05 1.26 50 3.14l7.45.61 1.38-15.82c.3-3.29-2.08-5.8-7.9-8.35l-2.38-1c2.9.62 5.58 1.29 7.92 2 7.1 2.15 10.26 4.24 10.34 6.93 0-2.71-3.18-4.83-10.34-7a141.83 141.83 0 0 0-21.71-4.31 151.81 151.81 0 0 0-18.82-1.32h-3.26c-7.93.31-11.49 1.7-11.86 4.67l-2 15.74Z" class="cls-6"/>
                    <path id="cam-drk-grey-pth1" d="m100.65 332.37 34-3.74v-64.82c0 15.68-.2 10.8 0-3.63-1.62-50.52-37.1-68.6-79.52-110.2-39.3-38.55 69.51-13.1 90.47-8a33.72 33.72 0 0 1 9.88-8.22l-.9-8.79a3 3 0 0 1 .19-1.5l1.87-4.32-31.81-2.86C57 112 15.7 116.07 7.9 117l.6 211.81c.93.47 10.16 4.68 44.64 4.68 37.86-.03 47.42-1.1 47.51-1.12Z" class="cls-6"/>
                </g>
                <g id="cam-light-grey">
                    <path id="cam-light-grey-pth6" d="m231.57 60.59-.1.23c22.27-.23 45.51-.23 69.33.09V21.44l-57.84 6Z" class="cls-7"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey-pth5" d="M216.3 61v-.26a1.1 1.1 0 0 1 0 .26Z" class="cls-7"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey-pth4" d="M136.27 63.19c13.76-.44 48.68-1.5 71.5-2v-.59l-.92-21.31c-.11-2.44-2.06-4-6.29-5.09 9.54.82 13.72 2.51 13.9 5.61l1.11 20v.36a2.62 2.62 0 0 1 0 .56 5.23 5.23 0 0 0 0-.56v-.36l-1.11-20c-.19-3.18-4.56-4.88-14.65-5.72-3.95-.34-8.55-.49-13.55-.49-4.64 0-9.64.13-14.76.43a214.94 214.94 0 0 0-22.66 2.29l-.92.22c-8.23 2.06-11.7 4.38-11.55 7.76l.79 18.06v.8Z" class="cls-7"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey-pth3" d="m144.73 37-1.26.22c-5 1-8.55 2-10.83 3.21 2.27-1.18 5.81-2.21 10.79-3.19Z" class="cls-7"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey-pth2" d="M217.89 324.34h-.23a4.91 4.91 0 0 1-4.67-3.48 4.89 4.89 0 0 1-4.36-3.74 4.88 4.88 0 0 1-2.83-1.25 5.05 5.05 0 0 1-1.48-2.6 4.89 4.89 0 0 1-2.64-1.37 4.84 4.84 0 0 1-1.36-2.66 4.89 4.89 0 0 1-3.86-4.28 5 5 0 0 1-2.65-1.61 4.87 4.87 0 0 1-1.13-2.77 4.8 4.8 0 0 1-2.47-1.68 5 5 0 0 1-1-3.22 5.07 5.07 0 0 1-2.79-1.87 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-.88-2.85 4.9 4.9 0 0 1-2.3-1.87 4.8 4.8 0 0 1-.76-3 4.87 4.87 0 0 1-3-4.94 4.94 4.94 0 0 1-2.62-5.3 4.86 4.86 0 0 1-2.66-5.24 5 5 0 0 1-1.87-2.26 4.89 4.89 0 0 1-.24-3.09 5.08 5.08 0 0 1-1.87-2.42 4.86 4.86 0 0 1-.13-3 4.68 4.68 0 0 1-1.74-2.41 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 .13-3.39 4.94 4.94 0 0 1-2-2.75 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 .13-3 5 5 0 0 1-1.53-2.58 4.8 4.8 0 0 1 .15-3.13 5 5 0 0 1-1.5-2.71 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 .38-3 5 5 0 0 1-1.31-2.67 4.85 4.85 0 0 1 .69-3.28 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-.81-5.95 4.81 4.81 0 0 1-1.06-2.79 4.69 4.69 0 0 1 .82-3 4.74 4.74 0 0 1-1-2.92 4.65 4.65 0 0 1 .88-2.84 4.87 4.87 0 0 1-.84-2.89 5 5 0 0 1 1.27-3.14 4.87 4.87 0 0 1 .21-6 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 .74-5.74 4.9 4.9 0 0 1-.5-3.05 5 5 0 0 1 1.37-2.66 4.87 4.87 0 0 1 1.34-5.73 4.8 4.8 0 0 1-.3-3.21 4.93 4.93 0 0 1 1.5-2.55 4.86 4.86 0 0 1 0-3 5 5 0 0 1 1.87-2.53 4.93 4.93 0 0 1 1.87-5.48 4.92 4.92 0 0 1 2.45-5.5 4.93 4.93 0 0 1 2.21-5.62 5 5 0 0 1 .25-2.92 5 5 0 0 1 2.24-2 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 2.74-5.07 4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.53-5.05 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 3.13-5.3 4.79 4.79 0 0 1 .95-2.82 4.84 4.84 0 0 1 2.79-1.87 4.93 4.93 0 0 1 .69-2.57h-30.96l.66 6.59a3 3 0 0 1-1.87 3.09c-.75.28-19 7.33-19 39.11v150.75h82.09l-.17-.17a4.92 4.92 0 0 1-4.69-3.75Zm-53-16.71h-.17a8 8 0 1 1 .17 0Z" class="cls-7"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey-pth1" d="M502.75 134.39a2.92 2.92 0 0 1 1.22-3.25l.31-.21 1.88-1-.32-.67-4.84-9.35-.45.28a3 3 0 0 1-3.74-.56l-3.43-3.89a3 3 0 0 1 .26-4.15 2.57 2.57 0 0 1 .55-.38 3.16 3.16 0 0 1 .93-.34c.32-.15.94-.78 1.33-2.36a14.21 14.21 0 0 0 .36-3.44c0-4.83-2-6.68-2.9-7.24h-9.4v17.42a3 3 0 0 1-2.24 2.88 44.83 44.83 0 0 1-6.42 1L472 127a3.18 3.18 0 0 1-.57.79 2.94 2.94 0 0 1-2.75 1.87h-62.49a5.33 5.33 0 0 1 1.09 1 4.89 4.89 0 0 1 1 3.24 4.84 4.84 0 0 1 2.79 1.87 4.73 4.73 0 0 1 .88 2.84 5 5 0 0 1 3.07 4.91 5 5 0 0 1 2.32 2 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 .63 2.92 4.81 4.81 0 0 1 2.15 2.08 4.86 4.86 0 0 1 .47 3.2 4.87 4.87 0 0 1 2.27 2.3 4.94 4.94 0 0 1 .39 3 4.75 4.75 0 0 1 1.87 2.26 4.82 4.82 0 0 1 .24 3.09 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 1.87 2.4 4.94 4.94 0 0 1 .14 3 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 1.6 5.8 4.85 4.85 0 0 1 1.86 5.73 4.9 4.9 0 0 1 1.53 2.56 4.77 4.77 0 0 1-.3 3.07 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 1.5 2.71 4.93 4.93 0 0 1-.37 3 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 .61 5.93 4.81 4.81 0 0 1 1.44 3 4.73 4.73 0 0 1-.63 2.92 4.9 4.9 0 0 1 .24 5.78A4.79 4.79 0 0 1 435 216a4.86 4.86 0 0 1 .84 2.88 4.74 4.74 0 0 1-1.27 3.14 4.91 4.91 0 0 1-.2 6 4.87 4.87 0 0 1-.75 5.73 4.81 4.81 0 0 1 .5 3.05 4.65 4.65 0 0 1-1.36 2.65 4.92 4.92 0 0 1 .31 3 4.81 4.81 0 0 1-1.66 2.75 4.77 4.77 0 0 1 .3 3.22 4.94 4.94 0 0 1-1.57 2.54 4.89 4.89 0 0 1 0 3 5.09 5.09 0 0 1-1.87 2.53 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-1.88 5.48 4.84 4.84 0 0 1-2.45 5.5 4.89 4.89 0 0 1-2.21 5.61 5 5 0 0 1-.44 3 4.94 4.94 0 0 1-2.19 2.19 4.78 4.78 0 0 1-.57 3 4.87 4.87 0 0 1-2.17 2 4.91 4.91 0 0 1-3.51 5.05 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-3.15 5.32 4.7 4.7 0 0 1-.95 2.82 4.94 4.94 0 0 1-2.79 1.87 4.86 4.86 0 0 1-4 4.89 4.89 4.89 0 0 1-4.42 4.77 4.88 4.88 0 0 1-1.4 3.27 4.82 4.82 0 0 1-3.22 1.44 4.85 4.85 0 0 1-4.85 4.44 4.1 4.1 0 0 1-1.21-.15 4.88 4.88 0 0 1-1.88 4.3 4.76 4.76 0 0 1-3.06 1.11 4.91 4.91 0 0 1-4.68 3.74 4.92 4.92 0 0 1-1.52 2.08h108.5V317h-9.88a8.75 8.75 0 0 1-8.14-9.21V201.7c0-30.57 14-42 18-44.66v-10.11a2.94 2.94 0 0 1 1-2.23 2.8 2.8 0 0 1 .53-.37h.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.85.21 25.23 25.23 0 0 0 9.36 3.57l1.1.17 6.25-3.74-.23-.68Zm-64.82 22.55a7.49 7.49 0 1 1 7.48-7.48 7.49 7.49 0 0 1-7.48 7.48Z" class="cls-7"/>
                </g>
                <g id="cam-light-grey2">
                    <path id="cam-light-grey2-pth6" d="M229.45 66.82 222.81 86l-2.13 16a4.57 4.57 0 0 1 1-.92 4.93 4.93 0 0 1 2.73-.84 4.45 4.45 0 0 1 .73 0 4.85 4.85 0 0 1 4.7-3.56h.35A5 5 0 0 1 234.6 94a3.75 3.75 0 0 1 .67 0 4.84 4.84 0 0 1 4.36-2.7h.79a4.77 4.77 0 0 1 2.21-2A5.1 5.1 0 0 1 246 89a4.82 4.82 0 0 1 2.51-2.24 5 5 0 0 1 1.87-.34 4.81 4.81 0 0 1 1.2.15 4.79 4.79 0 0 1 2.42-1.84 5 5 0 0 1 1.59-.26 4.59 4.59 0 0 1 1.51.24 4.79 4.79 0 0 1 2.53-1.87 5.36 5.36 0 0 1 1.38-.21 5.05 5.05 0 0 1 1.59.27 4.87 4.87 0 0 1 2.53-1.58 4.81 4.81 0 0 1 1.2-.15 4.9 4.9 0 0 1 2 .44 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 2.77-1.67 5.52 5.52 0 0 1 1-.09 4.68 4.68 0 0 1 2 .43 4.79 4.79 0 0 1 2.66-1.37h.79a5 5 0 0 1 2.26.54 5 5 0 0 1 2.79-1.31h.58a5 5 0 0 1 2.36.62 5 5 0 0 1 2.75-1.14h.37a4.87 4.87 0 0 1 2.88.95 4.91 4.91 0 0 1 3.15-1.27h.15a5 5 0 0 1 2.73.82 4.74 4.74 0 0 1 2.77-.87 4.51 4.51 0 0 1 .52 0V66.82c-24.59-.32-48.52-.3-71.41 0Z" class="cls-8"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey2-pth5" d="M480.43 85.12h-1.56a3 3 0 0 1-3-2.92v-5c0-.9-.23-1.35-.38-1.44q-8.24-.83-16.5-1.54l-2.32-.18-2.9-.25c-17.39-1.46-34.94-2.67-52.4-3.74l-7-.37-4.4-.23-4.77-.07 5.18 15a1.88 1.88 0 0 1 .13.58l3.84 28.68h70.06a107.79 107.79 0 0 0 14.14-.75V94.35a3 3 0 0 1 1.76-2.71l1-.44Z" class="cls-8"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey2-pth4" d="M378.87 69c-24.32-1.08-48.48-1.76-72.15-2.11v10.88a4.78 4.78 0 0 1 2.24 1 5 5 0 0 1 2.45-.65h.47a4.81 4.81 0 0 1 3 1.46 4.85 4.85 0 0 1 2.59-.75 4 4 0 0 1 .69 0 4.82 4.82 0 0 1 2.69 1.31 4.74 4.74 0 0 1 2.06-.47 6.76 6.76 0 0 1 .9 0 4.9 4.9 0 0 1 2.69 1.5 4.87 4.87 0 0 1 2-.42 4.54 4.54 0 0 1 1.1.14 4.74 4.74 0 0 1 2.56 1.53 4.65 4.65 0 0 1 1.69-.32 5.09 5.09 0 0 1 1.29.19 4.82 4.82 0 0 1 2.75 2.08 4.81 4.81 0 0 1 1.87-.38 5.12 5.12 0 0 1 1.5.25 5 5 0 0 1 2.45 1.76 4.56 4.56 0 0 1 1.27-.16 4.78 4.78 0 0 1 4.1 2.24 4.87 4.87 0 0 1 1.2-.15 4.82 4.82 0 0 1 1.87.39 5 5 0 0 1 2.27 1.88 4.22 4.22 0 0 1 .87-.1 5.14 5.14 0 0 1 2.08.47 4.85 4.85 0 0 1 2.3 2.28 3.55 3.55 0 0 1 .92-.09 4.79 4.79 0 0 1 2.26.56 4.88 4.88 0 0 1 2.15 2.26h.52a4.69 4.69 0 0 1 2.45.68 4.76 4.76 0 0 1 2 2.32h.36a4.83 4.83 0 0 1 4.51 3 4.92 4.92 0 0 1 4.71 3.74h.25a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 4.68 3.48 5 5 0 0 1 2.75 1.15 5.68 5.68 0 0 1 .75.8L384.71 86Z" class="cls-8"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey2-pth3" d="M156.4 73.13V71a3.06 3.06 0 0 1 .8-2.13 2.72 2.72 0 0 1 .72-.54l-15.92.55c-.26.45-.54.9-.82 1.33s-.88 1.23-1.35 1.87a21.57 21.57 0 0 1-1.6 1.92C124.1 88.66 92.29 93.6 62 96.35c-3.22.3-6.25.43-9.08.43C29 96.78 19 87.05 15 80.74l-1.44 5.19A3 3 0 0 1 11 88.1h-.9l-2.26 3.09V111c9.6-1.07 50.94-4.88 117.48-.6l32.68 2.96L156.4 75Z" class="cls-8"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey2-pth2" d="m225.28 60.65 10.82-31.46a121.63 121.63 0 0 0-13.91 31.49v.25h3.09Z" class="cls-8"/>
                    <path id="cam-light-grey2-pth1" d="m194.67 67.89-32.39 1.2v1.47l1.57 43h42a4.55 4.55 0 0 1 3.16-1.32 4.47 4.47 0 0 1 1.2.18 5.43 5.43 0 0 1 0-1.14 5.55 5.55 0 0 1 1.87-3.74 4.67 4.67 0 0 1 2-1.07l3-25a2.3 2.3 0 0 1 .14-.63l4.19-13.94Z" class="cls-8"/>
                </g>
                <circle id="shutter-bg-gradient" cx="299.19" cy="215.04" r="100.4" fill="url(#radial-gradient)"/>
                <g id="shutter-clipped" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
                    <path id="shutter" d="M399.18 172.8a108.87 108.87 0 1 0 8.53 42.2 108.23 108.23 0 0 0-8.53-42.2Zm4.42 18.2H287.85l44.63-77.53a1.12 1.12 0 0 0 .11-.25A107.54 107.54 0 0 1 403.6 191Zm-104.41-83.09a106.68 106.68 0 0 1 31.27 4.66l-57.73 100.27-44.73-77.5a1.09 1.09 0 0 0-.13-.17 106.74 106.74 0 0 1 71.32-27.26Zm-73 28.78L284 236.85h-89.44a1.09 1.09 0 0 0-.26 0 107.11 107.11 0 0 1 31.9-100.2Zm-31.42 102.38h115.75l-44.63 77.53a1.86 1.86 0 0 0-.1.25 107.57 107.57 0 0 1-71.02-77.78Zm104.42 83.11a106.68 106.68 0 0 1-31.27-4.66l57.73-100.27 44.74 77.5.12.17a106.72 106.72 0 0 1-71.32 27.26Zm73-28.78-57.85-100.17h89.47a1.18 1.18 0 0 0 .27 0 107.09 107.09 0 0 1-31.91 100.2Z" class="cls-2"/>
                </g>
                <ellipse id="glare" cx="264.95" cy="180.81" fill="url(#linear-gradient2)" rx="63.78" ry="43.48" transform="rotate(-45 264.955 180.812)"/>
            </svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/patricktrefry/cukr7zLw/4/

Ive attempting standard css styling techniques to modify the paths positioning but that doesnt appear to work with svg elements. I believe I need to set the paths' positioning from whatever its defaulted at to be center and vertically oriented in order for this to work as intended, but Im unsure of how I might do that.

Comment: Try using `transform-origin: 298.84px 215.044px;` which is the center of the shutter path

Comment: That does correct the placement issue, unfortunately the transform/animation still originates from the top left corner - then the path centers to the correct location once the scaling is complete: https://jsfiddle.net/patricktrefry/cukr7zLw/13/

Comment: I have resolved the issue, but come up against another, that will be something I need not address in this post though. By starting with the shutter path in the open position or at its largest scale, I can use keyframes to scale it down without affecting the transform-origin, apparently. Ill need to play around with it a bit more, but Ive at least resolved my initail problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/patricktrefry/cukr7zLw/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.camera-v3c {
  width:100% !important;
  height: auto !important;}
.camera-v3c .cls-1{fill:none;}
.camera-v3c .cls-2{fill:#231f20;}
.camera-v3c .cls-3{fill:#3d3b3c;}
.camera-v3c .cls-4{fill:#b5b6b6;}
.camera-v3c .cls-5{fill:#686969;}
.camera-v3c .cls-6{fill:#2d2e2d;}
.camera-v3c .cls-7{fill:#434343;}
.camera-v3c .cls-8{fill:#575757;}

.camera-v3c #shutter.cls-2{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    fill: black;
}

.camera-v3c:hover #shutter.cls-2{
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation-name: shutter;
    animation-duration: .3s;
}

@keyframes shutter {
  0% {
    fill: black;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);}
  25% {
    fill: rgba(52, 12, 25, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);}
  50% {
    fill: rgba(255,0,152,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);}
  75% {
    fill: rgba(52, 12, 25, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);}
  100% {
    fill: black;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);}
}
```

```html
<svg class="camera-v3c" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 746.25 746.25">
                <defs>
                    <style>
                        .cls-9{fill:url(#radial-gradient);}
                        .cls-10{clip-path:url(#clip-path);}
                        .cls-11{fill:url(#linear-gradient-white);}
                    </style>
                    <radialGradient id="radial-gradient" cx="373.12" cy="373.12" r="100.4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#231f20" stop-opacity="0"/>
                        <stop offset="0.44" stop-color="#231f20" stop-opacity="0.43"/>
                        <stop offset="0.89" stop-color="#231f20"/>
                    </radialGradient>
                    <clipPath id="clip-path">
                        <circle id="clip" class="cls-1" cx="373.12" cy="373.12" r="100.4"/>
                    </clipPath>
                    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-white" x1="281.23" y1="373.12" x2="348.19" y2="373.12" gradientTransform="matrix(0, 1.3, -1, 0, 712.01, -69.81)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
                        <stop offset="0.84" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path id="cam-light-grey4" class="cls-2" d="M587.46,300.22l-.33-.62-1.87-5.82a7.85,7.85,0,0,0,1.66-9.35l-.32-.62-4.84-9.36a8,8,0,0,0-4.53-3.95,13.41,13.41,0,0,0,.67-1.87,22.69,22.69,0,0,0,.6-5.33c0-8.65-4.51-12.54-6.46-13.81a7.81,7.81,0,0,0-4.3-1.29h-4.68l-.88-6a7.89,7.89,0,0,0-4.43-6v-.83a9,9,0,0,0-4.17-8.19,7.63,7.63,0,0,0-3.34-1.13c-3.74-.37-7.74-.74-11.75-1.1l1.87-14.07c1.37-10.84-11.22-14.6-15.85-16a147.3,147.3,0,0,0-23-4.58,162.3,162.3,0,0,0-19.82-1.39h-3.58c-4.47.19-15.66.64-18.71,8.91a136.53,136.53,0,0,0-6.83-13.29,7.83,7.83,0,0,0-4.79-3.63,7.9,7.9,0,0,0-1.4-5.84,93.1,93.1,0,0,0-8.85-10.38,7.92,7.92,0,0,0-4.94-2.3l-51.31-4.25h-.66a7.87,7.87,0,0,0-2.95.58,7.92,7.92,0,0,0-3-.58h-.66l-51.29,4.25a7.75,7.75,0,0,0-5,2.3,99.22,99.22,0,0,0-8.87,10.44,7.69,7.69,0,0,0-1.56,4.87,9.66,9.66,0,0,0-1.49.71,7.89,7.89,0,0,0-2.08,1.87,7.61,7.61,0,0,0-.51.75,127.27,127.27,0,0,0-7.18,13.25c-1.4-10.43-15-11.59-21.71-12.15-4.15-.34-8.92-.5-14.2-.5-4.85,0-10,.15-15.19.43a225.53,225.53,0,0,0-29.21,3.33c-6.78,1.33-20.89,4.09-20.25,15.45l.93,16.84-4.28.06a7.81,7.81,0,0,0-3.89,1.24,3.68,3.68,0,0,0,0-.47,8.79,8.79,0,0,0-1.24-3.59c-1.53-2.53-4.26-4.33-8.59-5.62a8.21,8.21,0,0,0-1-1.16c-1.14-1-3.55-3.27-14.74-3.27-1.63,0-3.35,0-5.13.15-2.52.15-5.2.39-7.93.73a91.53,91.53,0,0,0-16.94,3.59,19.66,19.66,0,0,0-7.48,4,8.66,8.66,0,0,0-1.87,2.66l-.51.28-.3.23-.62.43a15.7,15.7,0,0,0-3.25,3.21,9.74,9.74,0,0,0-1,1.71h-.4c-12.65.86-19.66,1.44-19.74,1.44h-1a7.56,7.56,0,0,0-2,.47l-3.74,1.42a7.91,7.91,0,0,0-4.15,3.74,7.87,7.87,0,0,0-5.17,5.37L80.73,239a8,8,0,0,0-3,2.41l-2.24,3A7.8,7.8,0,0,0,74,249.12V269a7.8,7.8,0,0,0,.58,3.13,7.63,7.63,0,0,0-.59,3l.59,211.81a7.91,7.91,0,0,0,4.29,7l.84.39a7.85,7.85,0,0,0,1.87,5.31l12.22,14.69a7.87,7.87,0,0,0,3.74,2.49,114.81,114.81,0,0,0,23.13,3.88c6.59.54,14.08.8,22.25.8,25.21,0,50.53-2.58,55.34-3.09a7.71,7.71,0,0,0,2.69-.82,8,8,0,0,0,3.22.71H518.49a8.18,8.18,0,0,0,1,0l24-3.09a7.79,7.79,0,0,0,4.75-2.45l13.83-15a7.72,7.72,0,0,0,2.23-5.46v-.4a7.85,7.85,0,0,0,2.28-5.61V475a7.52,7.52,0,0,0-.52-2.69,7.67,7.67,0,0,0,.52-2.71V322a7.69,7.69,0,0,0-.82-3.46,7.86,7.86,0,0,0,.82-3.46V312.7a33.44,33.44,0,0,0,4.74,1.16l1.46.23a9.55,9.55,0,0,0,4.94-1.09l6.25-3.65A7.87,7.87,0,0,0,587.46,300.22Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey3" class="cls-3" d="M272.49,372A100.84,100.84,0,0,0,373.33,472.84h0A100.84,100.84,0,1,0,272.49,372Z"/><g id="cam-btn"><path id="cam-btn-pth2" class="cls-4" d="M180.39,221.29a8.1,8.1,0,0,0-4.23-2.25,7.21,7.21,0,0,1-2.21,2.12,20.49,20.49,0,0,1-3.08,1.52L170,223l-1,.36c-1.72.56-3.74,1.12-5.95,1.63-3.41.79-6.87,1.42-10.34,1.87-2.66.31-5.26.56-7.73.71h-1.63a53.91,53.91,0,0,1-11.7-.58,8.92,8.92,0,0,1-3.89-1.41l-.15-.13-.32-.28h-.24l-.43.32A7.93,7.93,0,0,0,125,227a1.35,1.35,0,0,0-.33.74.9.9,0,0,0,.18.45,6.17,6.17,0,0,0,2.51,1.52,28,28,0,0,0,4.68,1.31,54.31,54.31,0,0,0,9.35,1,88.14,88.14,0,0,0,11.94-.52,85.45,85.45,0,0,0,12.9-2.4h.3a51.07,51.07,0,0,0,7.48-2.54,20.4,20.4,0,0,0,5.31-3.26,6.3,6.3,0,0,0,.77-.78l.21-.32a1.94,1.94,0,0,0,.22-.43.2.2,0,0,0,0-.15A.59.59,0,0,0,180.39,221.29Z"/><path id="cam-btn-pth1" class="cls-4" d="M130.67,221.85a5,5,0,0,0,1.87.6h.12a51.67,51.67,0,0,0,10.62.49h1.56c2.22-.13,4.69-.36,7.39-.7,3.32-.4,6.63-1,9.9-1.7,2-.47,3.89-1,5.5-1.51,1.18-.42,2.06-.77,2.75-1.09a7.45,7.45,0,0,0,1.16-.64c.58-.37.8-.63.86-.78a.25.25,0,0,0,0-.17c-.79-.71-5.76-1.55-14.15-1.07-2.22.12-4.71.34-7.48.68a82.33,82.33,0,0,0-15.38,3.23,13.34,13.34,0,0,0-4.72,2c-.19.19-.26.32-.24.38A.41.41,0,0,0,130.67,221.85Z"/></g><g id="cam-grey-pth1"><path id="cam-grey-pth12" class="cls-5" d="M373.14,241.37a131.74,131.74,0,0,0,0,263.47h0a131.74,131.74,0,0,0,0-263.47Zm0,247.57h0A115.82,115.82,0,1,1,489,373.12,116,116,0,0,1,373.12,488.94Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth11" class="cls-5" d="M273.5,279.71a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,.55-2.06H236.94l-1.48,3.24h35.29A4.94,4.94,0,0,1,273.5,279.71Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth10" class="cls-5" d="M539.54,277.62H470.9a3.78,3.78,0,0,1,.21.8,4.86,4.86,0,0,1,3.74,3.41H541l2-4.21Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth9" class="cls-5" d="M116.75,240.56a3.75,3.75,0,0,1,0-.67,2.09,2.09,0,0,1,0-.5v-.12l1.09-7.31c-12.13.82-19.09,1.38-19.71,1.44h-.88l-3.74,1.42c2.82,5.09,11.43,14.71,35.52,14.09C121.32,247.43,117.18,244.66,116.75,240.56Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth8" class="cls-5" d="M465.7,221.66c2.53.12,5.05.29,7.49.44-.08-.66-.3-2.12-.72-4.25L474,200.31a4.42,4.42,0,0,1,1.87-3.38c-6.19.48-9.06,1.87-9.36,4.53l-2,15.66v.07c.69,2.41,1.07,4,1.16,4.39Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth7" class="cls-5" d="M524.53,209.67l-1.37,15.82v.09l7.26.58,2.08-16.3a3.79,3.79,0,0,0,0-.58c-.07-2.69-3.23-4.78-10.33-6.93-2.34-.69-5-1.36-7.92-2l2.38.95C522.46,203.87,524.83,206.38,524.53,209.67Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth6" class="cls-5" d="M217.37,195.3c-5,1-8.52,2-10.79,3.19-2,1-3,2.18-3.17,3.53a3,3,0,0,0,0,.6l1,17,.15,1.87,5.72-.21.93,0v-.8l-.79-18.06c-.15-3.38,3.31-5.71,11.55-7.76l.91-.22.17,0c-1.51.23-2.94.47-4.31.72Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth5" class="cls-5" d="M280.78,197.36l.92,21.31v.59h0l7.73-.15h.78v0a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,0-.26h-.7a2.62,2.62,0,0,0,0-.56v-.36l-1.1-20c-.19-3.11-4.36-4.79-13.9-5.61C278.73,193.32,280.67,194.92,280.78,197.36Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth4" class="cls-5" d="M202.27,227.47l-9.73.41.41.58a6.15,6.15,0,0,1,1.72,3.63,6.71,6.71,0,0,1-1.76,5.16,46.82,46.82,0,0,0,12.61-7.37q.84-.7,1.59-1.44a16.48,16.48,0,0,0,1.13-1.22l-3.13.13Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth3" class="cls-5" d="M373.12,268.28A103.57,103.57,0,1,0,476.69,371.85,103.57,103.57,0,0,0,373.12,268.28Zm.25,204.56h0A100.84,100.84,0,1,1,474.17,372,100.84,100.84,0,0,1,373.33,472.84Z"/><path id="cam-grey-pth2" class="cls-5" d="M373.12,259.86A113.27,113.27,0,1,0,486.39,373.12,113.26,113.26,0,0,0,373.12,259.86Zm0,220.45A108.52,108.52,0,1,1,481.64,371.8,108.52,108.52,0,0,1,373.12,480.31Z"/></g><g id="cam-drk-grey"><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth7" class="cls-6" d="M450.66,221l-12.2-35.55-57.84-6v39.59c23,.36,46.48,1,70.07,2Z"/><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth6" class="cls-6" d="M457.09,221.38l2.47.14a139.78,139.78,0,0,0-13.75-32.92L457,221.4Z"/><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth5" class="cls-6" d="M175.3,496.33c-.35,0-9.71,1.12-48.2,1.12-20.59,0-32.66-1.46-39.54-2.92l12.22,14.69a108.27,108.27,0,0,0,21.54,3.57c29.94,2.42,68.88-1.51,76.1-2.28l.15-.28,9.17-17.38Z"/><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth4" class="cls-6" d="M440.2,492.27a5.33,5.33,0,0,1-1.07.82,5,5,0,0,1-2.36.6h-.69a4.94,4.94,0,0,1-4.36,2.69,3.48,3.48,0,0,1-.79,0,4.77,4.77,0,0,1-2.2,2,5,5,0,0,1-2,.43,5.1,5.1,0,0,1-1.4-.21,4.8,4.8,0,0,1-2.51,2.25,4.93,4.93,0,0,1-1.78.33,4.1,4.1,0,0,1-1.21-.15,4.68,4.68,0,0,1-2.38,1.87,5.36,5.36,0,0,1-1.59.27,5.1,5.1,0,0,1-1.5-.23,4.83,4.83,0,0,1-2.54,1.76,4.68,4.68,0,0,1-1.39.21,5.1,5.1,0,0,1-1.59-.27,5,5,0,0,1-2.52,1.59,5.46,5.46,0,0,1-1.2.14,5,5,0,0,1-2-.43,4.83,4.83,0,0,1-2.77,1.66,5.46,5.46,0,0,1-1,0,4.88,4.88,0,0,1-2-.43,4.73,4.73,0,0,1-2.65,1.37,5.21,5.21,0,0,1-.79,0,5,5,0,0,1-2.26-.56,4.77,4.77,0,0,1-2.79,1.3h-.58a4.9,4.9,0,0,1-2.34-.59,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-2.77,1.12h-.38a4.93,4.93,0,0,1-2.88-1,4.87,4.87,0,0,1-3.14,1.28h-.13a4.75,4.75,0,0,1-2.73-.83,4.81,4.81,0,0,1-2.79.88,4.89,4.89,0,0,1-2.92-1,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-2.71.83h-.29a4.8,4.8,0,0,1-2.76-1.07,5,5,0,0,1-2.46.65h-.46a4.91,4.91,0,0,1-3-1.46,4.79,4.79,0,0,1-2.58.75,4,4,0,0,1-.69,0,4.73,4.73,0,0,1-2.68-1.29,5.11,5.11,0,0,1-2.07.45,4.51,4.51,0,0,1-.9,0,4.92,4.92,0,0,1-2.7-1.5,4.82,4.82,0,0,1-2,.42,4.54,4.54,0,0,1-1.1-.14,4.72,4.72,0,0,1-2.55-1.51,5.16,5.16,0,0,1-1.7.3,4.33,4.33,0,0,1-1.29-.19,4.76,4.76,0,0,1-2.75-1.87,4.66,4.66,0,0,1-1.87.37,4.36,4.36,0,0,1-1.52-.24,4.79,4.79,0,0,1-2.41-1.76,5.16,5.16,0,0,1-1.29.19,4.76,4.76,0,0,1-1.71-.32,4.71,4.71,0,0,1-2.39-1.87,4.07,4.07,0,0,1-1.2.15,4.95,4.95,0,0,1-4.14-2.25,6.46,6.46,0,0,1-.88,0,4.85,4.85,0,0,1-4.37-2.73,4.71,4.71,0,0,1-.92,0,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-4.31-2.62H213.68l-9.36,17.95v.15H518.69l24-3.07,14-15H440.2Z"/><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth3" class="cls-6" d="M546,359.78V465.84c0,2.06,1.25,3.75,2.73,3.75h9.88V322C553.8,326.64,546,337.46,546,359.78Z"/><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth2" class="cls-6" d="M466.52,201.46c.3-2.66,3.17-4.05,9.36-4.53a4.42,4.42,0,0,0-1.87,3.38l-1.54,17.54c.42,2.13.64,3.59.72,4.25-2.44-.15-5-.32-7.49-.44l0-.08a.12.12,0,0,0,0,.13l0,0c16.69.84,33.38,1.87,50,3.14l7.46.61,1.37-15.82c.3-3.29-2.07-5.8-7.89-8.35l-2.38-.95c2.9.62,5.58,1.29,7.92,2,7.1,2.15,10.26,4.24,10.33,6.93,0-2.71-3.17-4.83-10.33-7A142.07,142.07,0,0,0,500.47,198a153.94,153.94,0,0,0-18.83-1.33h-3.25c-7.94.32-11.49,1.71-11.87,4.68l-2,15.74v0Z"/><path id="cam-drk-grey-pth1" class="cls-6" d="M174.59,490.45l34-3.74V421.89c0,15.68-.21,10.8,0-3.63-1.63-50.53-37.11-68.6-79.53-110.2-39.29-38.55,69.52-13.1,90.48-8a33.6,33.6,0,0,1,9.88-8.22l-.9-8.79a2.86,2.86,0,0,1,.19-1.5l1.87-4.32-31.81-2.86c-67.87-4.36-109.15-.25-117,.65l.6,211.81c.94.47,10.16,4.68,44.65,4.68C165,491.54,174.5,490.47,174.59,490.45Z"/></g><g id="cam-light-grey"><path id="cam-light-grey-pth6" class="cls-7" d="M305.5,218.67l-.09.23c22.27-.23,45.51-.23,69.33.09V179.52l-57.84,6Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey-pth5" class="cls-7" d="M290.23,219.1v-.26h0a2.17,2.17,0,0,1,0,.26Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey-pth4" class="cls-7" d="M210.21,221.27c13.76-.44,48.68-1.5,71.49-2v-.59l-.92-21.31c-.11-2.44-2-4-6.28-5.09,9.54.82,13.71,2.5,13.9,5.61l1.1,20v.36a2.62,2.62,0,0,1,0,.56h0a2.62,2.62,0,0,0,0-.56v-.36l-1.1-20c-.19-3.18-4.57-4.88-14.65-5.72-4-.34-8.56-.49-13.55-.49-4.64,0-9.64.13-14.77.43a215.21,215.21,0,0,0-22.66,2.29l-.91.22c-8.24,2-11.7,4.38-11.55,7.76l.79,18.06v.8Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey-pth3" class="cls-7" d="M218.67,195.06l-1.27.22c-5,1-8.55,2-10.82,3.21,2.27-1.19,5.8-2.21,10.79-3.19Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey-pth2" class="cls-7" d="M291.82,482.42h-.22a4.93,4.93,0,0,1-4.68-3.48,4.89,4.89,0,0,1-4.36-3.74,4.88,4.88,0,0,1-2.82-1.25,5,5,0,0,1-1.48-2.6,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-2.64-1.37,4.79,4.79,0,0,1-1.37-2.66,4.78,4.78,0,0,1-2.6-1.48,4.68,4.68,0,0,1-1.25-2.8,5.14,5.14,0,0,1-2.66-1.61,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-1.12-2.77,4.72,4.72,0,0,1-2.47-1.69,4.83,4.83,0,0,1-1-3.21,5,5,0,0,1-2.79-1.88,4.87,4.87,0,0,1-.88-2.84,4.84,4.84,0,0,1-3.07-4.86,4.89,4.89,0,0,1-3-4.94,4.92,4.92,0,0,1-2.61-5.3,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-2.66-5.24,5,5,0,0,1-1.87-2.26,4.89,4.89,0,0,1-.25-3.09,5.14,5.14,0,0,1-1.87-2.42,4.94,4.94,0,0,1-.13-3,4.84,4.84,0,0,1-1.74-2.41,4.94,4.94,0,0,1,.13-3.39,4.85,4.85,0,0,1-1.85-5.71,5.31,5.31,0,0,1-1.39-5.71,4.94,4.94,0,0,1-1.49-2.71,4.87,4.87,0,0,1,.37-3,5.1,5.1,0,0,1-1.31-2.67,5,5,0,0,1,.69-3.28,4.91,4.91,0,0,1-1.44-3,5,5,0,0,1,.64-2.92,4.89,4.89,0,0,1-1.07-2.79,4.76,4.76,0,0,1,.83-3,4.68,4.68,0,0,1-1-2.92,4.58,4.58,0,0,1,.88-2.84,4.85,4.85,0,0,1,.43-6,4.87,4.87,0,0,1,.2-6,4.86,4.86,0,0,1,.75-5.74,4.83,4.83,0,0,1,.86-5.71,4.87,4.87,0,0,1,1.35-5.73,4.74,4.74,0,0,1-.3-3.21,4.83,4.83,0,0,1,1.5-2.55,4.86,4.86,0,0,1,0-3,4.94,4.94,0,0,1,1.87-2.53,4.91,4.91,0,0,1,1.87-5.48,4.93,4.93,0,0,1,2.45-5.51,4.89,4.89,0,0,1,2.21-5.61,4.37,4.37,0,0,1,2.43-5.11,4.87,4.87,0,0,1,2.73-5.07,4.91,4.91,0,0,1,3.54-5.05,4.84,4.84,0,0,1,3.12-5.3,4.77,4.77,0,0,1,1-2.82,4.84,4.84,0,0,1,2.79-1.87,4.75,4.75,0,0,1,.69-2.57H234.81l.65,6.59a3,3,0,0,1-1.87,3.09c-.75.28-19,7.33-19,39.11V486.33h82.09a.65.65,0,0,1-.17-.16A4.93,4.93,0,0,1,291.82,482.42Zm-53-16.71h-.17a8,8,0,1,1,.17,0Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey-pth1" class="cls-7" d="M576.69,292.47a2.93,2.93,0,0,1,1.21-3.25l.32-.21,1.87-1-.32-.67L574.93,278l-.45.28a3,3,0,0,1-3.75-.56l-3.42-3.89a2.94,2.94,0,0,1,.26-4.15,2.78,2.78,0,0,1,.54-.38,3.21,3.21,0,0,1,.94-.34c.32-.15.94-.78,1.33-2.36a14.72,14.72,0,0,0,.35-3.44c0-4.83-2-6.68-2.9-7.24h-9.39v17.42a3,3,0,0,1-2.25,2.88,43.32,43.32,0,0,1-6.41,1l-3.86,7.88a2.91,2.91,0,0,1-.56.79,3,3,0,0,1-2.75,1.87H480.13a5.28,5.28,0,0,1,1.08,1,4.89,4.89,0,0,1,1,3.24,4.78,4.78,0,0,1,2.79,1.87,4.73,4.73,0,0,1,.88,2.84,4.92,4.92,0,0,1,3.07,4.9,5.06,5.06,0,0,1,2.32,2,4.82,4.82,0,0,1,.64,2.92,4.86,4.86,0,0,1,2.15,2.08,4.92,4.92,0,0,1,.47,3.2,4.85,4.85,0,0,1,2.26,2.3,4.94,4.94,0,0,1,.39,3,4.73,4.73,0,0,1,1.88,2.26,4.89,4.89,0,0,1,.24,3.09,4.94,4.94,0,0,1,2,5.37,4.88,4.88,0,0,1,1.61,5.8,4.83,4.83,0,0,1,2,2.75,4.75,4.75,0,0,1-.13,3A4.83,4.83,0,0,1,506,345a4.82,4.82,0,0,1,1.49,2.71,4.93,4.93,0,0,1-.37,3,4.83,4.83,0,0,1,.62,5.93,4.81,4.81,0,0,1,1.44,3,4.67,4.67,0,0,1-.64,2.92,4.88,4.88,0,0,1,.25,5.78,4.79,4.79,0,0,1,.13,5.75,4.91,4.91,0,0,1,.84,2.88,4.79,4.79,0,0,1-1.27,3.14,4.91,4.91,0,0,1-.21,6,4.84,4.84,0,0,1-.75,5.73,4.81,4.81,0,0,1,.51,3.05,4.73,4.73,0,0,1-1.37,2.65,4.92,4.92,0,0,1,.32,3,4.78,4.78,0,0,1-1.67,2.75,4.71,4.71,0,0,1,.3,3.22,4.94,4.94,0,0,1-1.57,2.54,4.89,4.89,0,0,1,0,3,5,5,0,0,1-1.87,2.52,4.93,4.93,0,0,1-1.87,5.49,4.87,4.87,0,0,1-.19,3,4.82,4.82,0,0,1-2.26,2.53,4.89,4.89,0,0,1-2.21,5.61,5,5,0,0,1-.45,3,4.84,4.84,0,0,1-2.19,2.19,4.78,4.78,0,0,1-.56,3,4.87,4.87,0,0,1-2.17,2,4.93,4.93,0,0,1-3.52,5,4.91,4.91,0,0,1-3.14,5.32,4.71,4.71,0,0,1-1,2.82,5,5,0,0,1-2.78,1.87,4.86,4.86,0,0,1-4,4.89,4.79,4.79,0,0,1-1.23,3.16,4.9,4.9,0,0,1-3.18,1.61,4.84,4.84,0,0,1-1.41,3.27,4.78,4.78,0,0,1-3.22,1.44,4.84,4.84,0,0,1-4.84,4.44,4.21,4.21,0,0,1-1.22-.15,4.87,4.87,0,0,1-1.87,4.3,4.78,4.78,0,0,1-3.07,1.11,16,16,0,0,0-6.19,5.82H558.16V475.07h-9.88a8.74,8.74,0,0,1-8.14-9.21V359.78c0-30.57,14-42,18-44.66V305a2.94,2.94,0,0,1,1-2.23,2.73,2.73,0,0,1,.52-.37h.19a2.94,2.94,0,0,1,2.84.21,25.23,25.23,0,0,0,9.36,3.57l1.1.17,6.25-3.74-.22-.68ZM511.86,315a7.49,7.49,0,1,1,7.49-7.48A7.48,7.48,0,0,1,511.86,315Z"/></g><g id="cam-light-grey2"><path id="cam-light-grey2-pth6" class="cls-8" d="M303.39,224.9l-6.64,19.22-2.14,16a5.08,5.08,0,0,1,1-.92,4.94,4.94,0,0,1,2.74-.84,4.45,4.45,0,0,1,.73,0,4.85,4.85,0,0,1,4.69-3.56h.36a4.93,4.93,0,0,1,4.41-2.78,3.86,3.86,0,0,1,.68,0,4.84,4.84,0,0,1,4.36-2.7h.78a4.82,4.82,0,0,1,2.21-2,5.13,5.13,0,0,1,3.39-.23,4.82,4.82,0,0,1,2.51-2.24,5.13,5.13,0,0,1,3.07-.19,4.81,4.81,0,0,1,2.37-1.87,5.09,5.09,0,0,1,1.59-.26,4.61,4.61,0,0,1,1.52.24,4.81,4.81,0,0,1,2.52-1.87,5.44,5.44,0,0,1,1.39-.21,5.05,5.05,0,0,1,1.59.27A4.87,4.87,0,0,1,339,239.4a4.79,4.79,0,0,1,1.19-.15,5,5,0,0,1,2,.43A5,5,0,0,1,345,238a5.55,5.55,0,0,1,1-.09,4.68,4.68,0,0,1,2,.43,4.75,4.75,0,0,1,2.66-1.37h.78a5,5,0,0,1,2.27.54,4.94,4.94,0,0,1,2.78-1.31h.58a5,5,0,0,1,2.36.62,5,5,0,0,1,2.75-1.14h.38a4.81,4.81,0,0,1,2.88,1,4.89,4.89,0,0,1,3.14-1.27h.15a5,5,0,0,1,2.73.82,4.82,4.82,0,0,1,2.77-.88h.53V224.9C350.21,224.58,326.27,224.6,303.39,224.9Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey2-pth5" class="cls-8" d="M554.36,243.2h-1.55a3,3,0,0,1-3-2.92v-5c0-.9-.22-1.35-.37-1.44q-8.24-.82-16.51-1.54l-2.32-.19-2.9-.24c-17.38-1.46-34.93-2.67-52.39-3.74l-7-.37-4.4-.23-4.77-.07,5.18,15a1.89,1.89,0,0,1,.14.58l3.83,28.68h70.06a107.94,107.94,0,0,0,14.15-.75V252.43a3,3,0,0,1,1.76-2.72l1-.43Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey2-pth4" class="cls-8" d="M452.81,227.11c-24.33-1.09-48.49-1.76-72.16-2.11v10.85a4.81,4.81,0,0,1,2.25,1,4.91,4.91,0,0,1,2.45-.65h.47a4.78,4.78,0,0,1,3,1.46,4.82,4.82,0,0,1,2.58-.75,4,4,0,0,1,.69,0,4.85,4.85,0,0,1,2.7,1.31,4.71,4.71,0,0,1,2.06-.47,6.61,6.61,0,0,1,.89,0,4.92,4.92,0,0,1,2.7,1.5,4.82,4.82,0,0,1,2-.42,4.63,4.63,0,0,1,1.11.14,4.78,4.78,0,0,1,2.56,1.53,4.64,4.64,0,0,1,1.68-.32,5.24,5.24,0,0,1,1.3.19,4.82,4.82,0,0,1,2.75,2.08,4.81,4.81,0,0,1,1.87-.38,5.34,5.34,0,0,1,1.49.24,5,5,0,0,1,2.44,1.76,4.52,4.52,0,0,1,1.27-.16,4.81,4.81,0,0,1,4.1,2.24,4.75,4.75,0,0,1,3.07.24,5,5,0,0,1,2.26,1.88,4.32,4.32,0,0,1,.88-.1,5,5,0,0,1,2.08.47,4.85,4.85,0,0,1,2.3,2.28,3.55,3.55,0,0,1,.92-.09,4.75,4.75,0,0,1,4.37,2.84h.53a4.71,4.71,0,0,1,2.45.68,4.8,4.8,0,0,1,2,2.32h.36a4.82,4.82,0,0,1,4.5,3,4.93,4.93,0,0,1,4.72,3.74h.24a5,5,0,0,1,3,1,4.91,4.91,0,0,1,1.68,2.45,5,5,0,0,1,2.75,1.15,5.16,5.16,0,0,1,.75.8l-3.27-24.7Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey2-pth3" class="cls-8" d="M230.33,231.21v-2.12a3,3,0,0,1,.81-2.13,2.84,2.84,0,0,1,.71-.54l-15.94.54c-.26.45-.55.9-.83,1.33s-.88,1.23-1.34,1.87a23.52,23.52,0,0,1-1.57,1.87c-14.13,14.71-45.94,19.65-76.28,22.4-3.22.3-6.25.43-9.07.43-23.86,0-33.87-9.73-37.88-16L87.5,244a3,3,0,0,1-2.56,2.17H84l-2.26,3.09V269.1c9.6-1.07,50.93-4.88,117.47-.6l32.66,2.94-1.58-38.36Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey2-pth2" class="cls-8" d="M299.22,218.73,310,187.27a121.94,121.94,0,0,0-13.9,31.49V219h3.09Z"/><path id="cam-light-grey2-pth1" class="cls-8" d="M268.6,226l-32.39,1.2v1.47l1.57,43h42a4.62,4.62,0,0,1,3.16-1.33,4.42,4.42,0,0,1,1.2.19,5.43,5.43,0,0,1,0-1.14,5.63,5.63,0,0,1,1.87-3.74,4.76,4.76,0,0,1,2-1.07l3-25a2.28,2.28,0,0,1,.13-.63L295.34,225Z"/></g><circle id="shutter-bg-gradient" class="cls-9" cx="373.12" cy="373.12" r="100.4"/><g id="shutter-clipped"><g class="cls-10"><path id="shutter" class="cls-2" d="M716.93,227.89a374.37,374.37,0,1,0,29.32,145.23A371.79,371.79,0,0,0,716.93,227.89Zm15.21,62.62h-398L487.6,23.94a3.47,3.47,0,0,0,.35-.85C609.4,63,703.16,164.54,732.14,290.51ZM373.12,4.77a367.19,367.19,0,0,1,107.51,16L282.16,365.55,128.31,99.08a3.51,3.51,0,0,0-.42-.59A366.89,366.89,0,0,1,373.12,4.77ZM122.18,103.7,321,448.11H13.39a4,4,0,0,0-.92.13,368.26,368.26,0,0,1-7.7-75.12C4.77,266.88,50,171,122.18,103.7Zm-108.07,352h398L258.64,722.3a4.56,4.56,0,0,0-.35.86C136.85,683.21,43.09,581.71,14.11,455.74Zm359,285.74a367.17,367.17,0,0,1-107.5-16L464.09,380.7,617.94,647.17a3.43,3.43,0,0,0,.42.58A366.9,366.9,0,0,1,373.12,741.48Zm251-98.94L425.22,298.13H732.86a4,4,0,0,0,.92-.12,368.24,368.24,0,0,1,7.7,75.11C741.48,479.37,696.27,575.25,624.07,642.54Z"/></g></g><ellipse id="glare" class="cls-11" cx="338.89" cy="338.89" rx="63.78" ry="43.48" transform="translate(-140.37 338.89) rotate(-45)"/>
            </svg>
```